# Ubuntu 17.10 - Can't change Bios settings, and can't boot into Bios from Grub

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 with gnome on a Lenovo B40-70. This install is actually an in-place upgrade from Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 that I did the day 17.10 came out. After that, I never needed to go into the Bios, except today, when I went into the Bios to boot into a LiveCD, because it wasn't showing in the `Fn + F10` Boot Options. There I realised that **I can't change any Bios settings at all.** When I change settings, they never get saved. I reboot to the Bios again, and the settings are the same as they were before. **I should point out, these aren't the default settings. I actually tried to reset to default settings, and even that didn't get saved.** Also, it seems like I can't boot from any USB drives. I have tried with a number of distros(multiple versions of ubuntu, Arch, manjaro) and they never show up in the boot options.

Then, I tried getting into the Bios from Grub, but it shows me this error - `Error: could not set EFI variable 'OsIndications'`

I'm not sure if these are Ubuntu issues, and whether these 2 issues are inter-related, but searching around, I found these 2 questions -

- [Unable to save BIOS options after Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970451/unable-to-save-bios-options-after-ubuntu-17-10-upgrade)
- [Error: could not set EFI variable 'OsIndications'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967903/error-could-not-set-efi-variable-osindications/968088)

These look very similar to the issues I have, and I don't have enough reputation to comment, so thats why I'm making this question.

Edit: It seems like a lot of people are facing this issue - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I ended up using for a similar issue (warning, ugly): Turn power off. Remove hard drive. Power-on. In my case the BIOS defaulted to looking for a USB boot in the absence of a hard drive. Then, as soon as USB starts to boot, plug the hard drive back in to stop it throwing a "No HDD!" fit.

Told you it was ugly. Worked though.

Comment: In my case, even bootable USB drives aren't visible in the boot options.

Answer (score 0):

Any updates? I have seen a case here, the guy have managed to make it work again by upgrading kernel to a newer version.

[Unable to make changes in BIOS after 17.10 installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984043/unable-to-make-changes-in-bios-after-17-10-installation/989771)

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. If you have a new question please [ask it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). See [Ubuntu 17.10's Laptop Issue Appears To Be Under Control, Fixable](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-17.10-Laptop-Fix)

Comment: Yeah mine got fixed with a kernel update too.