# Ubuntu 17.10 BIOS corruption

Tags: system-installation, uefi, 17.10, asus, bios

I have an Asus UX32LN with the Haswell chipset and American Megatrends UEFI.   Is it safe for me to use/install Ubuntu 17.10 ?

I have it installed already and it seems to work fine, but I'm worried about my EFI BIOS becoming corrupted.   How do I know if it's corrupted and can I continue to use 17.10 safely on this laptop?

Comment: if it was a problem then it would already be to late. If it is running then there is no problem. As far as I know, the issue only affects Lenovo computers. The problem is with their EFI not Ubuntu per se.

Comment: One main issue with the [bug you refer to](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147) is that (if you're affected) you are then no longer able to boot from a USB device (like an external CD or HDD). If you still can, then there should be no problem. See also https://askubuntu.com/q/984043/504066 and https://askubuntu.com/q/981878/504066. The first one also includes a solution.

Comment: @ravery Affected computers are mainly Lenovos but also [some (few) others](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147), like Acer, Toshiba, Dell, Mediacom. No mention of Asus, though.

Comment: @ravery I am able to install Ubuntu from a live-usb plus I tried toggling Secure Boot on/off with and saving,  the change survives booting.    So that would mean I have nothing to worry about?

Comment: @NaderNooryani indeed. Plus your system itself is not on the affected systems.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the bug ASUS is not on the affected list of systems. Besides all Lenovo's it also affects:

```
Acer Aspire E5-771G
Acer Aspire ES1-111M-C1LE
Acer TravelMate B113
Toshiba Satellite S55T-B5233
Toshiba Satellite L50-B-1R7
Toshiba Satellite S50-B-13G
Dell Inspiron 15-3531
Mediacom Smartbook 14 Ultra M-SB14UC
Acer Aspire E3-111-C0UM
```

So you are fine.

For users using one of these systems: all direct downloads that have this bug have been revoked so you can not download the broken version anymore. If you have an old download download 17.10 again to make sure you deleted the bugged version.

Or skip 17.10 and stick with 17.04. There is not a lot in 17.10 that is that different over 17.04 anyways.

---

For people already affected see [this notice](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147/comments/294) in the bug report.

Comment: from the bug report listed by perlduck, it seems installing kernel 4.14.9 fixes the broken systems.

Comment: oh cool didn't see that

Comment: Do these systems have anything in common like a specific GPU?

Comment: This is the technical cause @WinEunuuchs2Unix https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147/comments/330 The intel spi driver can write 2 bytes where it should be 1 byte.